# Can not click on an UI element in editor mode in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Usually you can click on an UI element (which is placed inside the canvas) in **editor** mode and the clicked element highlighted in the project hierarchy and you can see its properties in inspector. And it works this way if I create a new project.

But in my current project I can't click on any elemnt in canvas in editor mode because it's not responsive.

For example I have a button, I can click on it in **Play** mode, but **it's not responsive in Editor mode**. I mean **if I click on it in editor mode nothing occurs** (there is no highlighted object appears in hierarchy and I need to searching for this button in hierarchy by myself to open its properties in inspector)

This is incredibly annoying me.

Here is my button inside the canvas

[image]

Here is the button settings

[image]

Here is the canvas settings

[image]

Here is the event system settings:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gizmos option need to be active

[image]